# Query returning nothing when there is data in the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I use EntityFramework 4 + generated POCOs with Lazy loading **disabled**.
Let's say there are SQL tables named *Table1, Table2, Table3* and *Table4* and assume they contain some data.
Let's assume the simplified POCO representation of these tables looks like this:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int ID;
    public DateTime TableDate;
    public int Table2ID;
    public Table2 Table2;
    public ICollection<Table3> Table3s;
}

public class Table2
{
    public int ID;
    public string SomeString;
    public int Table4ID;
    public Table4 Table4;
}

public class Table3
{
    public int ID;
    public int Table1ID;
    public Table1 Table1;
    public decimal SomeDecimal;
}

public decimal Table4
{
    public int ID;
    public string SomeName;
}
```

If the following code would be executed:

```
Database DB = new Database(); // object context
var result = DB.Table1
    .Where(x => x.TableDate >= DateTime.MinValue);
```

EF would generate the following SQL statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[TableDate] AS [TableDate], 
[Extent1].[Table2ID] As [Table2ID]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[TableDate] >= @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

and the query would return the expected data.
However, if the following code would be executed:

```
Database DB = new Database(); // object context
var result = DB.Table1
    .Include("Table2")
    .Include("Table2.Table4")
    .Include("Table3")
    .Where(x => x.TableDate >= DateTime.MinValue);
```

EF would generate the following SQL statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[ID2] AS [ID], 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID1], 
[Project1].[TableDate] AS [TableDate], 
[Project1].[ID1] AS [ID2], 
[Project1].[SomeString] AS [SomeString], 
[Project1].[Table4ID] AS [Table4ID], 
[Project1].[ID3] AS [ID3], 
[Project1].[SomeName] AS [SomeName], 
[Project1].[ID4] AS [ID4], 
[Project1].[SomeDecimal] AS [SomeDecimal], 
[Project1].[Table1ID] AS [Table1ID]
FROM ( SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[TableDate] AS [TableDate], 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
[Extent2].[SomeString] AS [SomeString], 
[Extent2].[Table4ID] AS [Table4ID], 
[Extent3].[ID] AS [ID2], 
[Extent4].[ID] AS [ID3], 
[Extent4].[SomeName] AS [SomeName], 
[Extent5].[ID] AS [ID4], 
[Extent5].[SomeDecimal] AS [SomeDecimal], 
[Extent5].[Table1ID] AS [Table1ID], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent5].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM     [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Table2ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Table2ID] = [Extent3].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table4] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Table4ID] = [Extent4].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table3] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent5].[Table1ID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[TableDate] >= @p__linq__0)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ID2] ASC, [Project1].[ID] ASC, [Project1].[ID1] ASC, [Project1].[ID3] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

and the query would return nothing.

Why could this be happening?

*EDIT*

Following are SQL statements to create the above tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Table2ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[TableDate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2] FOREIGN KEY([Table2ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table2] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SomeString] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Table4ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table4] FOREIGN KEY([Table4ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table4] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table4]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SomeDecimal] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[Table1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table1] FOREIGN KEY([Table1ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table1]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table4](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SomeName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

*EDIT 2*

This query will also return no records and can serve as a minimal example:

```
Database DB = new Database();
var result = DB.Table1
    .Include("Table2")
    .Where(x => x.TableDate >= DateTime.MinValue);
```

Generated SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Table2ID] AS [Table2ID], 
[Extent1].[TableDate] AS [TableDate], 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
[Extent2].[SomeString] AS [SomeString], 
[Extent2].[Table4ID] AS [Table4ID], 
FROM  [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Table2ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[TableDate] >= @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Additionally, here is an excerpt from the .edmx:

```
<EntityContainer>
      <AssociationSet Name="FK_Table1_Table2" Association="MyModel.Store.FK_Table1_Table2">
        <End Role="Table2" EntitySet="Table2" />
        <End Role="Table1" EntitySet="Table1" />
      </AssociationSet>
</EntityContainer>

<!-- ... -->

<EntityType Name="Table2">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="SomeString" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
  <Property Name="Table4ID" Type="int" />
</EntityType>

<!-- ... -->

<EntityType Name="Table1">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
  <Property Name="TableDate" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Table2ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>

<!-- ... -->

<Association Name="FK_Table1_Table2">
  <End Role="Table2" Type="MyModel.Store.Table2" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Role="Table1" Type="MyModel.Store.Table1" Multiplicity="*" />
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="Table2">
      <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
    </Principal>
    <Dependent Role="Table1">
      <PropertyRef Name="Table2ID" />
    </Dependent>
   </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Comment: Something is convincing EF it needs an `INNER` rather than `LEFT` join from `Table1` to `Table2`. Can you tell us more about the sql schema, or come to a minimal example that goes wrong?

Comment: Please show the mapping you are using.

Comment: I have edited the question with SQL statements to create the above tables. In the meanwhile I will try to get to the minimal example that goes wrong.

Comment: I have also added a minimal example and the relevant code from the generated .edmx

Comment: What data do you have in database? What happens if you execute that query directly in the SSMS? The inner join is correct because you have non nullable FK and multiplicity 1.

Comment: @Ladislav good question. Inner join is simple, if there are no records in Table2 which match those in Table1, nothing is returned. I checked the data and it was not consistent (!). In *Table1* there were references to non existing `Table2ID`s. This is unexpected because I always enforce referential intergrity using FK constraints. How is it possible? Would be nice if someone could elaborate on this.

Comment: Sounds like the FK constraint is either not setup / not setup correctly or it is turned off. Anyway it is the reason for your problem - EF itself doesn't know about inconsistency in your database and it generates queries according to your mapping which says that this can never happen.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, no, the FK constraint IS set up correctly and turned on. We have clearly found the reason for the empty query result - but that expands the question as this behavior was completely unexpected. Are there any scenarios which could lead to having inconsistent FKs while FK constraints are set?

Comment: That deserves separate question with correct title and tags which will attract attention of SQL gurus ;) I believe that FK constrain will not allow you creating such records unless it is turned off. Try to execute this `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2]` - it should fail.

Comment: What could explain the missing PK is, DRI not set up correctly, records inserted before the DRI was set up,  records inserted with DRI was disabled.  Check the constraint and hopefully it find errors.  Try inserting a record in SSMS with invalid FK and verify it it fails.  The purpose of disable FK constraint is for faster inserts.  I use it for some large imports that I am (reasonably) confident have no constraint violations and then enable the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it was a problem with actual data in SQL server being inconsistent.
As stated [there](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp),

> The INNER JOIN keyword return rows when there is at least one match in both tables. If there are rows in "Table1" that do not have matches in "Table2", those rows will NOT be listed.

there is no reason for this query to fail, unless there is really no row in "Table2" which matches "Table1". This is odd though, since FK constraints are enforced, but that deserves another question and this case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Include()s are causing your query to not evaluate in the order you'd expect, so the TableDate is not available when your Where() is called. What if you force evaluation, then call your Where()?